# Display an alert based on a json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am having 2 portions of code (php and javascript).
In the PHP file, I use the function `json_encode()` to create a `JSON data` which will be sent to the Javascript file.

**PHP FIle**

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET["remove_code"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    $product_code   = filter_var($_GET["remove_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get the product code to remove

    if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code])) {
        unset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code]);
    }

    $total_items = count($_SESSION["products"]);

    if($total_items == 0){
        unset($_SESSION["products"]);
    }else{
        //Calculate total of items in the cart
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){ //loop though items and prepare html content

            $product_price = $product["price"];
            $product_quantity = $product["quantity"];

            $subtotal = $product_price * $product_quantity;

            $total += $subtotal;
        }
    }

    die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items, 'total'=>$total)));
}
?>
```

**Javascript File**

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".contentwrapper .content").on('click', 'a.removebutton', function() {
            var pcode = $(this).attr("data-code"); //get product code

            $.getJSON( "phpfile.php", {"remove_code":pcode}, function(data) {

                alert(data.items);// the total number of item
            });
    });
</script>
```

Anytime the query `$.getJSON( "phpfile.php", {"remove_code":pcode}...` is successful, an alert is displayed showing the `data.items`. The problem I am facing is that, when `data.items` is greater than or equal to 1 the alert is prompted, but when `data.items` is equal to 0, no alert is prompted.

Kindly help me solve this problem

Comment: Did you add a console.log() line to see if it is going into the success method. Maybe add an error handler to the Ajax call and see if that is triggered.

Comment: the ajax call is succesful. When when `data.items>=1`, the alert is prompted but the problem comes when `data.items=0`

Comment: Are you sure it it going into the success method...

Comment: yes, 101% Sure. because I am able to get `data.items`

Comment: What happens when you do `console.log("HERE", data.items);` Do you see the message in the console?

Comment: @epascarello, I just found that, when `data.items is equal to 0`, the ajax call is not successful

Comment: You should add some `isset($_SESSION["products"]) && is_array($_SESSION["products"])` in your code before you try to use it as an array. You are actually using `unset($_SESSION["products"])` in your code so the next time (or first time) you call it without having added products, it will fail.

Comment: In my php code, I just added `die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items)));` at the end of the condition `if($total_items == 0)` and it solves the problem. But I really can't explain what is happening. Up to now I do not really know the origin of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a PHP error. $total variable is only declared inside the 'else' condition, so when `($total_items == 0)` $total is undefined. But as you've called `die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items, 'total'=>$total)));` the server doesn't have a chance to complain (maybe returning no data and hence no alert). If you try declaring `$total = 0` before your condition it should also fix the issue, without having to die early.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Hope to see you around again next time.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that actually data variable is undefined/null e.t.c., see this for example, second alert is not shown. Instead an error is shown on the browser console.

```js
var data = {items:0};
alert(data.items);
data = null;
alert(data.items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `die(json_encode(array('items'=>$total_items)));` at the end of the condition `if($total_items == 0)` and it solves the problem. But I really can't explain what is happening. Up to now I do not really know the origin of the problem. Any explanation will be welcomed